# Redirect to a local route or render an ejs file without get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to create a get request without user interaction inside a function . There is a main html file that loaded in the browser windows at first but after the execution of the function ,it should automatically render another ejs file.Can I do that ?

Comment: second time render any ejs file?

Answer (score 0):

yes,

```
function test_function(){
    // some process if required
    router.get('/routes_name', (req, res) => {
        let o_verified = req.session.verified;
        if(o_verified != undefined && o_verified == 'true'){ /* any condition if required */
            res.render('auth/passwordreset.ejs',{title:'| Password Reset'});
        }else{
            res.redirect('/home') /* page/routes name */
        }
    });
} 
/* call function and automaticity render/redirect ejs file */
```

Comment: Thank you. However I found another solution. It can also be done with ajax requests